# Setting up Jenkins Continuous Integration and Selenium web application testing

Tags: php, selenium, continuous-integration, jenkins, capybara

I am trying to set up Jenkins to run our Cucumber features. I am a little lost when it comes to setting this up. Here are some details of our setup:

- Cucumber features with steps written in Ruby and PHP (using Cuke4PHP)
- PHP application (which often links to other PHP applications)
- Using Capybara and Selenium to exercise Javascript

In development environments, since our apps need to link to each other, we set up apache vhosts with domains like `http://developername.dev.exampleapp.com`

How should I set up this Jenkins environment to run our cucumber tests?

It seems like you would want to set up a virtual machine using VirtualBox or something in order to set up an environment similar to your production environment and serve the project from that virtual host. But then do you run the tests outside the virtual machine? Or do you run the tests on the virtual machine and report back to Jenkins? Do you set up virtual hosts when you provision the virtual machine? How do you set up your project to use an isolated database? How do you run your features in parallel so they don't take forever? If someone could shed some light I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you succeed to find the answer? I'm into building similar CI environment also for PHP. Could you please share your experiences?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have not finished setting this up. I will post an update once I have it working.

Answer (score 1):

We have recently started using [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) to setup a development environment on virtual machine in which we use folder sharing between host machine and guest Vm for application source code and application database itself is on Virtual machine. We haven't implemented with CI yet though.

For setting up your application environment for a build, you can use Vagrant to setup your applications environment. And assign a ip for your Vm which can handle Virtualhost for that ip by itself.

For running the tests, your selenium/acceptance tests should run from your host/build machine, considering a client and server architecture for you applications as pointed by Amber. But unit test should run on your VM itself. I don't have much idea about running features in parallel. But will share my experience once we have implemented whole process into CI.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your clients run their browsers on your production servers? (Hopefully not - hopefully they run them on their own computers!) Thus:

The server VM is the equivalent of your production server, so it's not where the tests should be running - Selenium tests run in the browser. Depending on how many browsers/what kinds of browser setups you want to test, you can either set up separate VMs with OS/browser combos to run the tests, or you can run them outside of a VM on a standard browser install.